# NUnit Jenkins plugin does not populate content from the 'output' tag

Tags: jenkins, nunit, specflow

I am using Specflow as the automation framework and am executing tests using NUnit console runner.

I also have configured the NUnit Jenkins plugin to execute test cases via Jenkins.

When I execute tests with Jenkins and publish reports, Jenkins does not populate content present in the **output** tag

Here is the snippet from the *result.xml* file.

Is there a way where I can populate the output content along with the feature list in Jenkins' published report?

```
<test-case id="0-1016" name="DemoTest" fullname="TestSolution.Features.DemoFeature.DemoTest" methodname="DemoTest" classname="DemoTestSolution.Features.DemoFeature" runstate="Runnable" seed="1408909031" result="Passed" start-time="2018-01-30 09:17:35Z" end-time="2018-01-30 09:18:45Z" duration="69.824025" asserts="0">
            <properties>
              <property name="Description" value="01 Demo test automation feature" />
              <property name="Category" value="test" />
            </properties>
            <output><![CDATA[Given I should be logged into portal
-> done: CommonsFeatureSteps.WhenIShouldBeLoggedInto("portal") (19.7s)
And I select Test Club from club drop down
-> done: CommonsFeatureSteps.GivenISelectTestClubFromClubDropDown("Test Coun...") (5.4s)
And I move to Dashboard Item page
-> done: CommonsFeatureSteps.GivenIMoveToAccountBalancePage("Dashboard Item") (5.1s)
And I add Test Card
-> done: TestCardSteps.GivenIAddTestCard("Test Card") (8.9s)
Then Card should be added
-> done: TestCardSteps.ThenCardShouldBeAdded() (0.2s)
]]></output>
          </test-case>
```

I want the output to be populated into the following format

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature has been included in the NUnit plugin version 0.23.

Now the Jenkins plugin displays standard output as well.